# Using forms and POST method to get URL parameters through Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, post, methods, parameters

So let's say there's a URL http://example.com/index.html/hello/hi where "hello" and "hi" are parameters.

How would you use javascript and forms method POST to extract the parameters?

Comment: Forms and POST have nothing to do with this.  You just need to extract the last parts of the path from the url.

Answer (score 0):

this could work...

```
var secondvar = window.location.href.split('/')[window.location.href.split('/').length];
var firstvar = window.location.href.split('/')[window.location.href.split('/').length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subject is a little bit vague. However, I thought I'd made an example of possibilities.
http://jsfiddle.net/tive/LjbPq/

The idea is to split the URL for each character /, in whatever way you received it.

```
var parts = document.URL.split("/");
```

Since split() returns an array (zero based), you need to distract 1 from the total length to get the last index.

```
var lastPart = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

Run this in a for loop, and you should get the idea as occurring in the example.

- [documentation on document.URL](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_url.asp) to retreive the complete URL
- [documentation on window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp) to use properties of a url (protocol, href, pathname, ...)