# Display Data from a form to another page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms

Users are able to select which product they want and how many of each as well from my products page. The products that the user selects pops up at the top of the form. It shows which items they chose, How much it is and gives the user a total. currently after the user select which products they want they hit the submit button and it directs them to the order page(which is the page that asks for name, billing address and payment information). How can the products that the user chooses to order pop up at the top of the order page as well?

Products page form:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="j.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<section>
<header>

</header>
<nav>
  <li><a href="index.htm" >Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="products.htm">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="order.htm">Order Form</a></li>
    </nav>



 <article>
    <div id="ordersummary">

    </div>
<form>

        <legend>Enter The Shipping Address</legend>

    <fieldset id="custInfo">

        <label id="firstNameLabel" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="firstName"  placeholder="First Name" required/>


        <label id="lnameLabel" for="lname">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required/>

        <label id="saddressLabel" for="saddress">Street Address:</label>
        <input name="saddress" id="saddress"  required/>


        <label id="scityLabel" for="scity">City:</label>
        <input type="text" name="scity" id="scity" placeholder="Tulsa" required/>


        <label id="sstateLabel" for="sstate">State:</label>
        <select id="sstate" name="sstate" required> 
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select a State</option> 
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option> 
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option> 
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option> 
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option> 
                <option value="CA">California</option> 
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option> 
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option> 
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option> 
                <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option> 
                <option value="FL">Florida</option> 
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option> 
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option> 
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option> 
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option> 
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option> 
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option> 
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option> 
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option> 
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option> 
                <option value="ME">Maine</option> 
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option> 
                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option> 
                <option value="MI">Michigan</option> 
                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option> 
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option> 
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option> 
                <option value="MT">Montana</option> 
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option> 
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option> 
                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option> 
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option> 
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option> 
                <option value="NY">New York</option> 
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option> 
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option> 
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option> 
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option> 
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option> 
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option> 
                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option> 
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option> 
                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option> 
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option> 
                <option value="TX">Texas</option> 
                <option value="UT">Utah</option> 
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option> 
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option> 
                <option value="WA">Washington</option> 
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option> 
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option> 
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>



        <label id="szipLabel" for="szip">Zip Code:</label>
        <input name="szip" id="szip" placeholder="xxxxx (-xxxx)"  required/>






    </fieldset>

    <legend>Billing Address</legend>

    <fieldset id="billingInfo">

        <label id="baddressLabel" for="baddress">Street Address:</label>
        <input name="baddress" id="baddress"  required/>

        <label id="bcityLabel" for="bcity">City:</label>
        <input type="text" name="bcity" id="bcity" placeholder="Tulsa" required/>

        <label id="bstateLabel" for="bstate">State:</label>            
        <select id="bstate" name="bstate" required> 
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select a State</option> 
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option> 
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option> 
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option> 
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option> 
                <option value="CA">California</option> 
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option> 
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option> 
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option> 
                <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option> 
                <option value="FL">Florida</option> 
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option> 
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option> 
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option> 
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option> 
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option> 
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option> 
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option> 
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option> 
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option> 
                <option value="ME">Maine</option> 
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option> 
                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option> 
                <option value="MI">Michigan</option> 
                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option> 
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option> 
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option> 
                <option value="MT">Montana</option> 
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option> 
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option> 
                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option> 
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option> 
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option> 
                <option value="NY">New York</option> 
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option> 
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option> 
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option> 
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option> 
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option> 
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option> 
                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option> 
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option> 
                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option> 
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option> 
                <option value="TX">Texas</option> 
                <option value="UT">Utah</option> 
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option> 
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option> 
                <option value="WA">Washington</option> 
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option> 
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option> 
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>


        <label id="bzipLabel" for="bzip">Zip Code:</label>
        <input name="bzip" id="bzip" placeholder="xxxxx (-xxxx)" required/>



    </fieldset>


    <legend>Credit/Debit Card</legend>

    <fieldset id="CreditInfo">

        <label id="ccardLabel" for="ccardtype">Credit Card Type:</label>
        <select id="ccardtype" name="ccardtype" required> 
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option> 
                <option value="AL">Visa</option> 
                <option value="AK">AMEX</option> 
                <option value="AZ">Discovery</option>
                <option value="AZ">MasterCard</option>
        </select>


        <label id="ccardnoLabel" for="ccardno">Credit Card Number:</label>
        <input name="ccardno" id="ccardno" required/>


        <label id="ccardexpLabel" for="ccardexp">Credit Card Exp. Date:</label>
        <input name="ccardexp" id="ccardexp" placeholder="mm/yy" required/>



    </fieldset>

                <p>
            <button id="submitButton" onclick="return validateForm();">Submit</button>
            <button id="clearButton" type="reset" >Clear</button>

        </p>


    </form>




</article>

    <footer>
    Copyright 2013 philtography.blah
    </footer>
    </section>
```

products.js

```
function Totals() {
var photos = ['photo1_', 'photo2_', 'photo3_', 'photo4_', 'photo5_', 'photo6_'];
var prices = 'price';
var quantities = 'quantity';
var subtotals = 'subtotal';
var prodText = 'text';
var total = 0;
var orderSum = "<table><tr><th>Product</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Sum</th>    </tr>";
for (var i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
var price = document.getElementById(photos[i] + prices).value;
var quantity = document.getElementById(photos[i] + quantities).value;
document.getElementById(photos[i] + subtotals)
    .innerHTML = parseInt(price) * parseInt(quantity);
total += price * quantity;
if (quantity > 0) {
    orderSum += "<tr><td>" + document.getElementById(photos[i] + prodText).value + "   </td><td>" + "$" + price + "</td><td>"+quantity+"</td><td>" + "$" + (price * quantity) +   "</td></tr>";
}
}
orderSum += "</table>";    
document.getElementById("ftotal").innerHTML = total;
document.getElementById("ordersummary").innerHTML = orderSum;    
}

function setup() {

var theForm = document.getElementById("orderform");

var amounts = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for(var i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++){
amounts[i].onchange = Totals;
}

}
window.onload = setup;
```

order.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="j.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<section>
<header>

</header>
<nav>
  <li><a href="index.htm" >Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="products.htm">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="order.htm">Order Form</a></li>
    </nav>



<article>
    <div id="ordersummary">

    </div>
<form>

        <legend>Enter The Shipping Address</legend>

    <fieldset id="custInfo">

        <label id="firstNameLabel" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="firstName"  placeholder="First Name" required/>


        <label id="lnameLabel" for="lname">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required/>

        <label id="saddressLabel" for="saddress">Street Address:</label>
        <input name="saddress" id="saddress"  required/>


        <label id="scityLabel" for="scity">City:</label>
        <input type="text" name="scity" id="scity" placeholder="Tulsa" required/>


        <label id="sstateLabel" for="sstate">State:</label>
        <select id="sstate" name="sstate" required> 
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select a State</option> 
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option> 
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option> 
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option> 
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option> 
                <option value="CA">California</option> 
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option> 
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option> 
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option> 
                <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option> 
                <option value="FL">Florida</option> 
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option> 
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option> 
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option> 
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option> 
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option> 
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option> 
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option> 
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option> 
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option> 
                <option value="ME">Maine</option> 
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option> 
                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option> 
                <option value="MI">Michigan</option> 
                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option> 
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option> 
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option> 
                <option value="MT">Montana</option> 
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option> 
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option> 
                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option> 
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option> 
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option> 
                <option value="NY">New York</option> 
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option> 
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option> 
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option> 
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option> 
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option> 
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option> 
                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option> 
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option> 
                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option> 
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option> 
                <option value="TX">Texas</option> 
                <option value="UT">Utah</option> 
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option> 
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option> 
                <option value="WA">Washington</option> 
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option> 
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option> 
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>



        <label id="szipLabel" for="szip">Zip Code:</label>
        <input name="szip" id="szip" placeholder="xxxxx (-xxxx)"  required/>






    </fieldset>

    <legend>Billing Address</legend>

    <fieldset id="billingInfo">

        <label id="baddressLabel" for="baddress">Street Address:</label>
        <input name="baddress" id="baddress"  required/>

        <label id="bcityLabel" for="bcity">City:</label>
        <input type="text" name="bcity" id="bcity" placeholder="Tulsa" required/>

        <label id="bstateLabel" for="bstate">State:</label>            
        <select id="bstate" name="bstate" required> 
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select a State</option> 
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option> 
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option> 
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option> 
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option> 
                <option value="CA">California</option> 
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option> 
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option> 
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option> 
                <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option> 
                <option value="FL">Florida</option> 
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option> 
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option> 
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option> 
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option> 
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option> 
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option> 
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option> 
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option> 
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option> 
                <option value="ME">Maine</option> 
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option> 
                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option> 
                <option value="MI">Michigan</option> 
                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option> 
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option> 
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option> 
                <option value="MT">Montana</option> 
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option> 
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option> 
                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option> 
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option> 
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option> 
                <option value="NY">New York</option> 
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option> 
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option> 
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option> 
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option> 
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option> 
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option> 
                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option> 
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option> 
                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option> 
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option> 
                <option value="TX">Texas</option> 
                <option value="UT">Utah</option> 
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option> 
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option> 
                <option value="WA">Washington</option> 
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option> 
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option> 
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>


        <label id="bzipLabel" for="bzip">Zip Code:</label>
        <input name="bzip" id="bzip" placeholder="xxxxx (-xxxx)" required/>



    </fieldset>


    <legend>Credit/Debit Card</legend>

    <fieldset id="CreditInfo">

        <label id="ccardLabel" for="ccardtype">Credit Card Type:</label>
        <select id="ccardtype" name="ccardtype" required> 
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option> 
                <option value="AL">Visa</option> 
                <option value="AK">AMEX</option> 
                <option value="AZ">Discovery</option>
                <option value="AZ">MasterCard</option>
        </select>


        <label id="ccardnoLabel" for="ccardno">Credit Card Number:</label>
        <input name="ccardno" id="ccardno" required/>


        <label id="ccardexpLabel" for="ccardexp">Credit Card Exp. Date:</label>
        <input name="ccardexp" id="ccardexp" placeholder="mm/yy" required/>



    </fieldset>

                <p>
            <button id="submitButton" onclick="return validateForm();">Submit</button>
            <button id="clearButton" type="reset" >Clear</button>

        </p>


    </form>




</article>

    <footer>
    Copyright 2013 philtography.blah
    </footer>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the GET method in your form you can fetch the parameters with `document.URL` on the target page.

**HTML**

```
<form method="GET" action="yourpage.html">
...
</form>
```

When submitting this form the url will look like: yourpage.html?param1=1&param2=2

**JavaScript**

```
var parts = document.URL.split("?"); // the right part of the URL
var params = parts[1].split("&"); // [param1=1, param2=2]
```

For a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767140/using-forms-and-post-method-to-get-url-parameters-through-javascript/11769722#11769722) I've made a fiddle which demonstrates this.

http://jsfiddle.net/tive/LjbPq/